NAIP acquisition time?
I'm using Google Earth Engine (geemap) to look at NAIP imagery. The image ID shows the acquisition date, and the metadata shows the acquisition time (system:time_start and system:time_end) in milliseconds since the Unix Epoch - however, when I convert to date/time, it just shows up as 12:00:00 am GMT on the day of acquisition. This is obviously not correct, as the images are taken during the day. Is there a way to find the acquisition time (to the second) of NAIP imagery?
EDIT: here's a snippet of code to get the metadata for a specific image:
import geemap

ee.Initialize()

x03 = ee.Image("USDA/NAIP/DOQQ/n_4207018_nw_19_1_20030731")

x03.get('system:time_start')


Hi! Could you provide a working snippet of code so we can replicate the error?

https://naip-image-dates-usdaonline.hub.arcgis.com/  Has all the IDATE as 00:00 - for 2024 process you can see the dashboard https://www.arcgis.com/apps/dashboards/2017f8e63aa5472fb8cc4a711f38a99e

The NAIP 'images' are actually processed orthophoto mosaics made up of many smaller images, some times spanning multiple days of collection.  There is no single acquisition time.

Interesting! I probably should have known that. For coastal areas under tidal influence (such as the one I'm looking at), does USGS ensure that the tidal height is similar for all images in a single 'image'/mosaic?
